# Deleting a created axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, axes

How do I remove an axes object from a figure in Matlab?
I created one using

```
haxis = axes('position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);
```

Now I want to remove it! (i.e. not just hide the lines - actually delete the object?)

I tried `cla` but that just removes objects drawn in the axes.

`clf` will do it but also removes all other axes, which I need to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, just saying what you want to do works:

```
delete(haxis)
```

I believe the same is true for other graphics handles.

Comment: Hah! I never thought of that. And wasn't easily found in the help - no mention of it under `axes` etc.